# mmenu IE11 problems

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, mmenu, domcontentloaded

I'm just using the mmenu script and I got an IE11 a syntax error on this line.

```
    "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
```

The whole code looks like here

```
document.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        new Mmenu( "#my-menu" );
    }
);
```

Code is out of the official documentation -> https://mmenujs.com/docs/core/

[image]

[image]

I tried some different solution i found with function(), etc.
But non of them work for me.
Maybe some one else got this problem and can help me out.

**Update**:

Now i got **Object doesn't support property or method 'append'** on IE11

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    
        new Mmenu( "#menu", {
           "extensions": [
              "pagedim-black",
              "position-right"
           ],
           navbar : {
                title : " "
            },
           "navbars": [
              {
                 "position": "top",
                 "content": [
                    "prev",
                    "title"
                 ]
              },
              {
                 "position": "bottom",
                 "content": [
                    "<div class='navshort'></div>",
                 ]
              }
           ]
        });     

} );
```

Comment: IE doesn't understand `=>` notation ... you'll need to transpile or rewrite your code

Comment: Ah oky, its not my code ;) Do you have any solution how to rewrite it?

Comment: `document.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        new Mmenu( "#my-menu" );
    }
);`

Comment: `its not my code` - isn't it? whose code is it? That's not mmenujs code, that's code you would've written to use mmenujs :p

Comment: :D :P You are right :) Now that error is gone.  But i use a bit more lager code. Now i got -> Object doesn't support property or method 'append'  - I think i will need to wrote them :) But thanks for you help.

Comment: `Object doesn't support property or method 'append'` - most likely https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append#Browser_compatibility - on their github, they do mention polyfills required for IE

Comment: i.e. For Internet Explorer 10 and 11, you''ll need [some polyfills](https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default%2CElement.prototype.matches%2CElement.prototype.prepend%2CElement.prototype.closest)

Comment: Ah i see, thanks :)

Comment: That works -> all error gone -> https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Array.prototype.forEach%2CElement.prototype.matches%2CElement.prototype.prepend%2CElement.prototype.closest%2CElement.prototype.append%2CElement.prototype.before%2CNodeList.prototype.forEach

Answer (score 0):

as per mmenu doc, https://mmenujs.com/docs/

> As of version 8, the mmenu.js plugin by default only supports ECMAScript 6 compliant browsers. For Internet Explorer 10 and 11, you'll need the JavaScript polyfills included in the package.
>
> Version 7 should work in Internet Explorer 10 and 11 without any shortcomings, it should also work to some degree in Internet Explorer 9, but you'll need a matchMedia polyfill.

for IE 10 and 11 you need polyfills

Comment: Yes - now it works -> https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Array.prototype.forEach%2CElement.prototype.matches%2CElement.prototype.prepend%2CElement.prototype.closest%2CElement.prototype.append%2CElement.prototype.before%2CNodeList.prototype.forEach